# Getting a list of required gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

What is the best way to get the list of gems that are required?

- The pseudo variable `$"` (loaded feature) gives a list of all files loaded, some of which are files internally loaded by gems, and others are non-gem files that were loaded.
- The `Gem::Specification.map(&:name)` gives all gems that are installed on the system, including ones that are not loaded at the time.

I want the intersection of these, i.e., the list of gems (main files) that are loaded at the moment. But since the former points to full path of files such as `.so`, `.rb`, and the latter points to the name of `.gem` files, matching them and taking the intersection is not trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Gem.loaded_specs
```

It returns a `Hash` of gem names (as `Strings`) to `Gem::Specification` objects.

See the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem.html#loaded_specs) or the [RubyGems documentation](http://docs.seattlerb.org/rubygems/Gem.html#attribute-c-loaded_specs).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
Gem::Specification
.select{|g| g.instance_variable_get(:@loaded)}
.map(&:name)
```

will return the names of the loaded gems.

Answer (score 1):

I think this might do the trick for you:

```
Gem::Specification.select do |gem|
  $".find{|f| f.start_with?(gem.full_gem_path)}
end.map(&:name)
```